# Overpass query works on overpass-turbo.eu, but not from API call

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I wrote the following query for Overpass:

```
[out:json];
(
  way["highway"](around:500,44.6759305,8.1672113);
  -
  (way["highway"="primary"](around:500,44.6759305,8.1672113););
);
out geom;
make stats way_id_length=set(id() + "-" + length());
out;
```

This query works fine in https://overpass-turbo.eu, giving me the result that I expect.

However, when I use the API url I get a BadRequest error:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(way[%22highway%22](around:500,44.6759305,8.1672113);-(way[%22highway%22=%22primary%22](around:500,44.6759305,8.1672113);););out%20geom;make%20stats%20way_id_length=set(id()%20+%20%22-%22%20+%20length());out;
```

I don't understand why I have this problem. Reading the error it seems to have to do with `make stats way_id_length=set(id() + "-" + length());` but I don't understant how to resolve this.

Thanks, Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems a bit inefficient. We will fix this first and change it to:

```
[out:json];
way[highway][highway!=primary](around:500,44.6759305,8.1672113);
out geom;
make stats way_id_length=set(id() + "-" + length());
out;
```

overpass turbo can create a proper download link by hitting "Export" button -> "raw data directly from Overpass API". Just use that with your download tool of choice, in this example *curl*.

```
curl "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3B%0Away%5Bhighway%5D%5Bhighway%21%3Dprimary%5D%28around%3A500%2C44.6759305%2C8.1672113%29%3B%0Aout%20geom%3B%0Amake%20stats%20way_id_length%3Dset%28id%28%29%20%2B%20%22-%22%20%2B%20length%28%29%29%3B%0Aout%3B"
```

Comment: Thank you very munch for the fast and precise answer. Thanks also for the query tip.